# WPF adaptative user interface

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

Hi fellow programmers,

I'm working on a WPF software that uses a Canvas to display and move graphic objects. 
When the user clic on an object, I need to display a panel with the selected object's properties.
These properties are different for each object, one can have a displayed text, another a background color or a scale value.

What is the best way to program this ?

I have 9 objects type, I'm searching for something more elegant than creating my controls in panels and switch betwenn then for every graphic object type.

Thank you for your help.

Edit - to show design code :

The dock panel for generated Wpf controls to display properties.

```
  <DockPanel x:Name="pnlProperties"  Width="200" Grid.Column="2" Background="red">

        <Grid x:Name="GridProperties" Grid.Column="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid Margin="0,2,0,25" Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="55"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="55"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="55"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="55"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="95"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="95"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="55"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="55"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="55"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <!--  ***** Label ***** -->
                <Label x:Name="lblLabel1" Content="test Prop" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="16"/>

                <Label x:Name="lblLabel2" Content=" Prop 2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="16"/>

                <Label x:Name="lblLabel3" Content=" Prop 3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="16"/>

                <Label x:Name="lblLabel4" Content=" Prop 4" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="16"/>

            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
```

The Canvas that displays the MovableObject (userControl) of each graphic objects :

```
<UserControl x:Class="DashEditor.Views.ScreenView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DashEditor.Views">

<Canvas x:Name="ObjectsCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="800" Height="480" AllowDrop="True" Background="Black" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ObjectsCanvas_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" >
    <Image x:Name="imgFond" Stretch="Fill" Source="/DashEditor;component/assets/FondXAP.png" Width="800" Height="480"/>
</Canvas>
```

One of the graphic object class :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
[XmlRoot("XapLabel")]
public class XapLabel : IXapGraphicObject
{
    private int _id;
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    private MovableObject _Control;
    [XmlIgnore]
    public MovableObject Control
    {
        get
        {
            return _Control;
        }

        set
        {
            _Control = value;
        }
    }

    private Point _pos;
    public Point Pos
    {
        get
        {
            return _pos;
        }

        set
        {
            _pos = value;
        }
    }

    public IXapGraphicObject getXapParent(MovableObject Control)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public ObjectType Type
    {
        get
        {
            return ObjectType.Label;
        }
    }

    public XapLabel()
    {
    }

    public void ConnectToMoveEvent()
    {
        _Control.OnObjectTranslating += _Control_OnObjectTranslating;
    }

    private void _Control_OnObjectTranslating(Vector displacement)
    {
        Pos = Pos + displacement;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your design code? it'll help to see your approach

Comment: The Label Class isn't finished, there is only a position property that could be displayed.

Comment: I've found a similar project [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27121/Stream-YouTube-Videos-in-WPF) that allows the user to drag Elements on a canvas. Please have a look. If it doesn't solve your query then let me know

Comment: Thank you but the draging object part of my project is working, I need to create a property panel which works like Visual Studio's.

Comment: When you clic on a label or a text box you have different properties displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done something similar to this, if you are familiar with MVVM:-

For the canvas, I used an `ItemsControl` bound to an `ObservableCollection` of your "graphic objects", to which you'll be adding objects that you want to appear on the canvas. You'll also need to change the ItemsControl's panel template to a Canvas:-

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Width="800" Height="480" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Your "graphic object" classes need to expose `double` properties (say "X" and "Y"), to control the object's position on the canvas.

Next, create a XAML `DataTemplate` for each of these classes, to define their visual appearance. The data template should include the following bindings:

```
<Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
<Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
```

For the property grid, rather than write your own, look at the free Xceed Toolkit community edition ([here](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/)), which has a very good `PropertyGrid` control. You bind its `SelectedObject` property to the selected object, but read the documentation - there are plenty of decent features.

(If you are using MVVM then remember to change your classes to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and raise the PropertyChanged event in the setters).

For the drag and drop functionality, you should just be able to set the selected object's X and Y values within the mouse move event.

Not a full solution I know, but will hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you andrew, I will read the Xceed documentation, this PropertyGrid seems to be exactly what I need. I'm using MVVM, I'll add PropertyChanged event to the graphic object classes.

Comment: I accepted your answer, Xceed PropertyGrid is what I needed, it displays the public properties of the SelectedObject and adapt rows automaticaly, perfect ^^. When I moved an object, there was a delay, but I launched the updateposition event in another tast, its smooth now. Thank you Andrew !